# Calculating Compound Interest without math.pow in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

I need to calculate the monthly compounding interest in a  savings account that is getting a monthly deposit. The variables I have to work with: 
  **monthly savings** ( Eg. I deposit $125.75 each month)
  **months** (Eg. I deposit the same for 15 months)
  **APR** (the ANNUAL interest is 5.65%)
Now I need to calculate the total savings amount, which for the given numbers here, the final answer should be $1958.88.
In essence, I am working with A = P(1 + r/12)^(12*t), where P is the amount I deposit * months, r is the APR, and t is the months/12 to get the "how many years"

The catch here is that I can not use the math.pow() as a requirement on the assignment, so my best guess is that I am to calculate it with a for/while loop similar to the following:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double monthlySavings = 125.75;
    double APR = 5.65;
    int months = 15;
    int monthCount = 0;
    double totalSavings = 0;


    while (monthCount < months)  
    {
        totalSavings += monthlySavings + (1+APR/12/100);
        mothCount++;
    }

    System.out.printf("Your total savings will be $%.2f\n", totalSavings);
}
```

The above code is NOT the correct solution, but its the closest i've come. The problem is that I am applying the interest to the monthly savings each time before it accumulates to the total. eg.  it adds 125.75*interest for 15 deposits. What it SHOULD do is start with 125.75*interest then add 125.75, and then take the interest of the amount you have total so far, then add 125.75 and take the interest of the total amount again, and so on for the amount of months.

This is probably a lot easier than I am making it out to be, but I have tried for hours with adding different placeholder variables, but I am lacking some crucial concept, please help!

Comment: Write a `pow` method that raises something to a power by repeated multiplication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop for the number of months

```
 for (int monthNumber = 0; monthNumber < numberOfMonths; monthNumber++)
 {
 }
```

then for each each month, add the interest then add the monthly savings.  In that order, the other way around you end up with interest on money you just deposited, which is wrong.

```
totalSavings *= (APR / 12 / 100); //Although I would have separate variable for this 
totalSavings += monthlySavings;
```

you don't really need to keep a month count but I prefer for loops.

Comment: Thanks! This is a much better idea than what I came up with. The only thing I had to change was put totalSavings +=monthlySavings first, and change totalSavings *= (1 + APR/12/100)

Answer (score 0):

After re-reading my question, I had an epiphany.. As I originally thought, the answer was a lot easier than I was making it out to be.

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    double monthlySavings = 125.75;
    double APR = 5.65;
    int months = 15;
    int monthCount = 0;
    double placeHolder = 0;
    double totalSavings = 0;


    while (monthCount < months)  
    {
        placeHolder += monthlySavings;
        totalSavings = placeHolder * (1+APR/12/100);
        placeHolder = totalSavings;
        monthCount++;
    }

System.out.printf("Your total savings will be $%.2f", totalSavings);
}
```

Comment: Your only problem now is that `(1+APR/12/100)^12` !=  `(1+APR/100)`. Your monthly interest rate is off. I don't think you can calculate it without ever using Math.Pow though...

Comment: Pretty sure you are right, and the $1958.88 amount is wrong in the first place... But the teacher is the one that gives the final amount I am supposed to get and says not to use Math.Pow, and my goal is to get the same answer as him, however flawed the assignment is.

Comment: Well... good luck with your faulty teacher then. The assignment nearly makes sense though. I would just change it to "calculate the compound interest without using Math.Pow more than once".